# Postgresql doesn't use memory for caching

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

The server I use has 8GB memory. I set the appropriate effective_cache_size and shared_buffers configuration parameters for Postgresql. Here is the `show all;` query result:

```
allow_system_table_mods off
application_name    
archive_command (disabled)
archive_mode    off
archive_timeout 0
array_nulls on
authentication_timeout  1min
autovacuum  on
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor 0.1
autovacuum_analyze_threshold    50
autovacuum_freeze_max_age   200000000
autovacuum_max_workers  3
autovacuum_naptime  1min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay    20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit    -1
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor  0.2
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold 50
backslash_quote safe_encoding
bgwriter_delay  200ms
bgwriter_lru_maxpages   100
bgwriter_lru_multiplier 2
block_size  8192
bonjour off
bonjour_name    
bytea_output    hex
check_function_bodies   on
checkpoint_completion_target    0.5
checkpoint_segments 3
checkpoint_timeout  5min
checkpoint_warning  30s
client_encoding UTF8
client_min_messages notice
commit_delay    0
commit_siblings 5
config_file /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
constraint_exclusion    partition
cpu_index_tuple_cost    0.005
cpu_operator_cost   0.0025
cpu_tuple_cost  0.01
cursor_tuple_fraction   0.1
custom_variable_classes 
data_directory  /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
DateStyle   ISO, MDY
db_user_namespace   off
deadlock_timeout    1s
debug_assertions    off
debug_pretty_print  on
debug_print_parse   off
debug_print_plan    off
debug_print_rewritten   off
default_statistics_target   100
default_tablespace  
default_text_search_config  pg_catalog.english
default_transaction_deferrable  off
default_transaction_isolation   read committed
default_transaction_read_only   off
default_with_oids   off
dynamic_library_path    $libdir
effective_cache_size    6GB
effective_io_concurrency    1
enable_bitmapscan   on
enable_hashagg  on
enable_hashjoin on
enable_indexscan    on
enable_material on
enable_mergejoin    on
enable_nestloop on
enable_seqscan  on
enable_sort on
enable_tidscan  on
escape_string_warning   on
exit_on_error   off
external_pid_file   /var/run/postgresql/9.1-main.pid
extra_float_digits  0
from_collapse_limit 8
fsync   on
full_page_writes    on
geqo    on
geqo_effort 5
geqo_generations    0
geqo_pool_size  0
geqo_seed   0
geqo_selection_bias 2
geqo_threshold  12
gin_fuzzy_search_limit  0
hba_file    /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
hot_standby off
hot_standby_feedback    off
ident_file  /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf
ignore_system_indexes   off
integer_datetimes   on
IntervalStyle   postgres
join_collapse_limit 8
krb_caseins_users   off
krb_server_keyfile  FILE:/etc/postgresql-common/krb5.keytab
krb_srvname postgres
lc_collate  en_US.UTF-8
lc_ctype    en_US.UTF-8
lc_messages en_US.UTF-8
lc_monetary en_US.UTF-8
lc_numeric  en_US.UTF-8
lc_time en_US.UTF-8
listen_addresses    *
lo_compat_privileges    off
local_preload_libraries 
log_autovacuum_min_duration -1
log_checkpoints off
log_connections off
log_destination csvlog
log_directory   pg_log
log_disconnections  off
log_duration    off
log_error_verbosity default
log_executor_stats  off
log_file_mode   0600
log_filename    postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
log_hostname    off
log_line_prefix %t 
log_lock_waits  off
log_min_duration_statement  2s
log_min_error_statement error
log_min_messages    warning
log_parser_stats    off
log_planner_stats   off
log_rotation_age    1d
log_rotation_size   10MB
log_statement   none
log_statement_stats off
log_temp_files  -1
log_timezone    Turkey
log_truncate_on_rotation    off
logging_collector   on
maintenance_work_mem    16MB
max_connections 100
max_files_per_process   1000
max_function_args   100
max_identifier_length   63
max_index_keys  32
max_locks_per_transaction   64
max_pred_locks_per_transaction  64
max_prepared_transactions   0
max_stack_depth 2MB
max_standby_archive_delay   30s
max_standby_streaming_delay 30s
max_wal_senders 0
password_encryption on
port    5432
post_auth_delay 0
pre_auth_delay  0
quote_all_identifiers   off
random_page_cost    4
replication_timeout 1min
restart_after_crash on
search_path public, "$user", public
segment_size    1GB
seq_page_cost   1
server_encoding UTF8
server_version  9.1.13
server_version_num  90113
session_replication_role    origin
shared_buffers  2GB
shared_preload_libraries    
silent_mode off
sql_inheritance on
ssl on
ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH
ssl_renegotiation_limit 512MB
standard_conforming_strings on
statement_timeout   0
stats_temp_directory    pg_stat_tmp
superuser_reserved_connections  3
synchronize_seqscans    on
synchronous_commit  on
synchronous_standby_names   
syslog_facility local0
syslog_ident    postgres
tcp_keepalives_count    9
tcp_keepalives_idle 7200
tcp_keepalives_interval 75
temp_buffers    8MB
temp_tablespaces    
TimeZone    Turkey
timezone_abbreviations  Default
trace_notify    off
trace_recovery_messages log
trace_sort  off
track_activities    on
track_activity_query_size   1024
track_counts    on
track_functions none
transaction_deferrable  off
transaction_isolation   read committed
transaction_read_only   off
transform_null_equals   off
unix_socket_directory   /var/run/postgresql
unix_socket_group   
unix_socket_permissions 0777
update_process_title    on
vacuum_cost_delay   0
vacuum_cost_limit   200
vacuum_cost_page_dirty  20
vacuum_cost_page_hit    1
vacuum_cost_page_miss   10
vacuum_defer_cleanup_age    0
vacuum_freeze_min_age   50000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age 150000000
wal_block_size  8192
wal_buffers 16MB
wal_keep_segments   0
wal_level   minimal
wal_receiver_status_interval    10s
wal_segment_size    16MB
wal_sender_delay    1s
wal_sync_method fdatasync
wal_writer_delay    200ms
work_mem    16MB
xmlbinary   base64
xmloption   content
zero_damaged_pages  off
```

I use Postgresql as backend database for a website. I run a stress test on the website so it performs variety of queries on Postgresql. I monitor the system and see that Postgresql creates new processes for select queries which uses some memory, returns the data and kills itself. The main Postgresql process uses 2GB virtual memory (shared_buffers) but as far as I can see there is no persistent data in memory for caching. It uses around 78mb all the time. I know that Postgresql heavily uses operating system cache, but `top` shows that memory usage is quite low in total.

Is it a problem or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is normal. `effective_cache_size` tries to hint PG for the amount of diskbuffering that the OS tries to maintain. (your shared_buffers+effective_cache_size is rather high though, it should be _less_ than the total availabe memory) Please monitor IOstat/vmstat to see if swapping occurs. If so: lower the settings to 1GB+4GB or so. Setteing random_page_cost to alower value will help for bulky queries + network disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the `RES` column, any backend process only gets attributed for the memory it actually touched, and if each one only lives for the duration of a single transaction or query, it is probably only touching a tiny amount of memory during its life.  `top` does not attribute OS cache to individual processes, so the high usage of OS cache is not visible through that tool.  `vmtouch` would be better for doing that.  But in general, if the %wa time is low, then the cache must be operating as well as it needs to be.

As far whether there is a problem, only you can know that--you ran the stress test.  How did it do?

Comment: I was expecting an improvement when I run the same queries a few times but the the response time for all queries were almost same. I tried vmtouch, the size of data directory is 1gb but only 50mb were in memory according to vmtouch. I tried -vt argument in order to load all data in postgresql into memory, vmtouch successfully loaded the data but again, the response time for same queries were same.

Comment: BTW, the average response time is 3 seconds. The select query uses 100% cpu for 3 seconds and returns the response. here is the explain analyze if you want to look at it: http://explain.depesz.com/s/3VBS

Comment: If the data is already cached, running the same query repeatedly won't be expected to lead to an improvement.  If you run vmtouch -vt, and then shortly later run vmtouch -v, does it find that the data was still in memory?  What is %wa?  From the EXPLAIN, it looks like your query is justifiably CPU intensive and caching has little to do with it; but it is hard to say definitively without also seeing the query itself.  Also, explain (analyze,buffer) with track_io_timing=on would help a lot.

Comment: I tested vmtouch -v again and 100% of data directory is in memory. Yes, that's what's I was thinking about the bottleneck but doesn't Postgresql cache joins and group by operations? The most expensive operation in the query I executed is group by parts. Here is an example facet query: http://pastebin.com/tSBqPx49 The dataset part is dynamic, but in this specific example query, I don't have any filter on products. The most expensive part in this query is the last union especially "vehicle_grup_id" table because this table has ~1m rows...

Comment: ..It seems track_io_timing is available for 9.2 so I executed this explain analyze on my computer since the version in server is 9.1: http://explain.depesz.com/s/p1kD @jjanes